# What kind of sort is this? - C

Tags: c, sorting

I wrote this for an assignment a while back to sort an array of stucts I made, by weight and then alphabetically by name, was wondering what kind of sort this is?

```
void sortPR(stuct m *arr, int n_nodes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++) {

        // Sort in descending order for weight
        for (int k = i + 1; k < n_nodes; k++) {

            // If weight equal, sort alphabetically
            if (arr[i].weight == arr[k].weight) {

                // Sort alphabetically
                if (strcmp(arr[i].name, arr[k].name) > 0) {
                    swap(&arr[i], &arr[k]);
                }
            } else if (arr[i].weight < arr[k].weight) {
                swap(&arr[i], &arr[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @TauqeerAkhtar this is not a bubble sort comparison condition. This looks like selection sort

Comment: selection sort minimizes the number of swaps :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the selection sort with redundant swappings of elements.

Usually for the selection sort only one swapping of elements is done after the inner for loop while the inner for loop only determines the index of the element with which the element with the index i will be swapped if it is required.

Comment: I think this is it!!!

Answer (score 1):

`sortPR` performs a variation of [*Selection Sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) with extra swapping to sort the array by decreasing `weight` with a secondary key on `name`, sorted in lexicographical order for identical `weight`.

The performance is quite bad, with a time complexity is **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** in all cases (unlike insertion sort), but for small arrays, this does not matter much and the implementation is straightforward, easy to get right. Quicksort on the contrary is complicated and easy to get wrong.

Furthermore, unlike bubble sort and insertion sort, selection sort does not guarantee stability, relative order of elements that compare identical is not preserved: **B<sub>1</sub>**, **B<sub>2</sub>**, **A** would sort as **A**, **B<sub>2</sub>**, **B<sub>1</sub>**. Your implementation behaves differently but has this defect too.

The lexicographical order is not exactly the same as alphabetic order: case will matter and the relative order of letters, digits and punctuation depends on the character set used in the system.

Here is a modified version, closer to the typical selection sort, with fewer swaps:

```
void sortPR(stuct m *arr, int n_nodes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++) {
        int i1 = k;

        // Sort in descending order for weight
        for (int k = i + 1; k < n_nodes; k++) {

            // If weight equal, sort alphabetically
            if (arr[i].weight == arr[k].weight) {

                // Sort alphabetically
                if (strcmp(arr[i].name, arr[k].name) > 0) {
                    i1 = k;
                }
            } else if (arr[i].weight < arr[k].weight) {
                i1 = k;
            }
        }
        if (i != i1) {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[i1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no comparison of adjacent items.. How is it bubble sort?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: omg Im so sorry for the confusion hahah, I looked up a random sort online and I adapted it, and now I don't know what I've adapted it into >.<

Comment: @SurajRao: indeed a variation of insertion sort :).